# Selenium get three text values with inconsistent href

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```html
<tr class="odd deactivate" xeid="EiWNVsrN"><td class="table-time datet t1509231600-1-1-0-0 ">23:00</td><td class="name table-participant"><a href="/soccer/panama/lpf-2017-2018/tauro-san-francisco-EiWNVsrN/"><span class="bold">Tauro</span> - San Francisco</a></td><td class="center bold table-odds table-score">4:2</td><td class="odds-nowrp result-ok" xodd="1.56" xoid="E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0ft"><a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0ft');return false;" xparam="odds_text">1.56</a></td><td class="odds-nowrp" xodd="3.43" xoid="E-2pdfcxv498x0x0"><a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-2pdfcxv498x0x0');return false;" xparam="odds_text">3.43</a></td><td class="odds-nowrp" xodd="5.46" xoid="E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0fu"><a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0fu');return false;" xparam="odds_text">5.46</a></td><td class="center info-value">34</td></tr>
```

```
<tr class="odd deactivate" xeid="EiWNVsrN">
    <td class="table-time datet t1509231600-1-1-0-0 ">23:00</td>
    <td class="name table-participant"><a href="/soccer/panama/lpf-2017-2018/tauro-san-francisco-EiWNVsrN/"><span class="bold">Tauro</span> - San Francisco</a></td>
    <td class="center bold table-odds table-score">4:2</td>
    <td class="odds-nowrp result-ok" xodd="1.56" xoid="E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0ft"><a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0ft');return false;" xparam="odds_text">1.56</a></td>
    <td class="odds-nowrp" xodd="3.43" xoid="E-2pdfcxv498x0x0"><a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-2pdfcxv498x0x0');return false;" xparam="odds_text">3.43</a></td>
    <td class="odds-nowrp" xodd="5.46" xoid="E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0fu"><a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-2pdfcxv464x0x6g0fu');return false;" xparam="odds_text">5.46</a></td>
    <td class="center info-value">34</td>
</tr>
```

Hello I am trying to extract some text values from the above code. There are hundreds of instances of the above code. The values for this specific `<tr>` are 1.56, 3.43 and 5.46. Each I need to be separate. Here is the code I have tried for the first value of 1.56 but it is not consistent across all the code because the class names alternate between "odds-nowrp" and "odds-nowrp result-ok".

```
Home_odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='odds-nowrp']")
Home_odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='table-matches']/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
```

The first text 1.56 I would like to pull in Home_odds
The second text 3.43 I would like to pull in Draw_odds
The third text 5.46 I would like to pull in Away_odds

I have been able to extract the other information that I need but these three text values I cannot consistently pull across the entire page script. The text appears at the beginning as xodd="value" and at the end of the `<a href`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below xpath

```
(//td[contains(@class, 'odds-nowrp')]/a)[1]  for Home_odds
(//td[contains(@class, 'odds-nowrp')]/a)[2]  for Draw_odds
(//td[contains(@class, 'odds-nowrp')]/a)[3]  for Away_odds
```

you can also use findelements also and store the results in List. then use list index to iterate for 1st, 2nd and 3rd index

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath like this to extract values

for 1.56

```
//a[contains(@xparam,'odds_text') and contains(text(),'1.56')]
```

for 3.43

```
//a[contains(@xparam,'odds_text') and contains(text(),'3.43')]
```

for 5.46

```
//a[contains(@xparam,'odds_text') and contains(text(),'5.46')]
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention but the text values (1.56,etc) will be different numbers for every one. Would I just leave it blank?

Comment: if you leave it blank it locate all the 3 fields

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the text `1.56`, `3.43` and `5.46` you can use the following code:

```
Home_odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='odds-nowrp result-ok']/a").get_attribute("innerHTML")
Draw_odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='odds-nowrp result-ok']//following::td[1]/a").get_attribute("innerHTML")
Away_odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='odds-nowrp result-ok']//following::td[2]/a").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```